# Why does MainActivity in Android extend different activity classes at different times?

Tags: android

Could you please help me with this question?

When I create a new project I see MainActivity extending the Activity class or AppCompatActivity. Why does this happens? What is the reason behind changing the default settings of android project everytime? What are the other classes that MainActivity can extend? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity which extends Activity. This is called Polyfill (in Web development) to support older Versions of Android to use newer features (e.g. Material Design)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Actvity` has support for system ActionBar which was introduced in Android 3.0 (API level 11).

`AppCompatActivity` has interface to work with ActionBar from support library and can be used with API Level 7).

Comment: Toolbar is also used with AppcompatActivity by using support library android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: So, does it mean that we should always use AppCompatActivity? Then what is the meaing of having other Activity classes that can be extended?

Comment: @Marat I use it always even if my target is above 3.0. Why? I very often use ViewPager and it forces me to use Fragments from support library and then I have to call getSupportedFragmentManger from AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support some features like actionbar, to lower API level of android so use AppcompateActivity.For example, if you extend youractivity with Activity class then you can not use actionbar in api level 7 because actionbar feature added in api level 11.

```
AppCompatActivity provide backward compatibility for new features
```

Comment: No, its depend on what feature you want to use in activity or what API level supported by your APP, For example, if you don't want to use actionbar for api level 7 (min api level in menifest) then use AppCompateActivity. if min api level is 11 then use Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

> I see MainActivity extending the Activity class or AppCompatActivity.

Well it depends on you what type Activity you uses in your project.when you creates  a new project it asks for `Activity`type. like `FragmentActivity` etc.